# Keyboard opens and immediately disappears on Android

Tags: reactjs, keyboard, native, expo, react-native-flatlist

Issue: Keyboard instantly disappears when selecting input box in dynamically populated list.  Only occurs when selecting an input box near the bottom of the page.

Occurs on: Android (works on ios)

The app was created with Expo, and I haven't ejected.

Currently using KeyboardAwareFlatlist, however issue still occurs if I switch this to just FlatList.  Below is the code for the TextInput.  Please let me know if you would like any other code.

```
<TextInput
  style={{
  color: 'black',
  backgroundColor: 'white',
  padding: 5,
  fontSize: 16,
  marginBottom: 10,
  }}
  keyboardType={'numeric'}                                       
  returnKeyType='done'
  onChangeText={(text) => this.setDuration(text, index)}
  value={item.duration.toString()}
 />
```

video of issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U3Ps_tz4Uxw&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Hi @Steve, did you find any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 4):

So I was running into something very similar, though it had nothing to do with FlatList.

My fix was to add `removeClippedSubviews={false}` like so:

```
<Input
    id="description"
    label="Description"
    errorText="Enter a valid Description"
    keyboardType="default"
    removeClippedSubviews={false}
    autoCorrect
    multiline
    type="text"
    required
/>
```

What also worked, though it looked kinda dirty was by using:

`keyboardDismissMode='none'`

Like so:

```
<Input
    id="title"
    label="Title"
    keyboardDismissMode='none'
    errorText="Enter a valid title"
    autoCapitalize="sentences"
    keyboardType="default"
    returnKeyType="next"
    onInputChange={inputChangeHandler}
    required
/>
```

Let me know if that works. Hopefully, this answer reached you in a timely manner. I hate un-answered Stack Overflow questions

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but I ran into the same problem. The solution in my case was to add ```removeClippedSubviews={false}``` to my FlatList props and NOT my "TextInput". 
I dynamically generate the content as well and is using React Native (0.70) without Expo. 
Remember to reload the app, hope this helps someone in need!

Answer (score 1):

i'm facing same problem and i'm use

**android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan" //under AndroidManifist.xml**

my problem solve

Answer (score 0):

Make your outer "wrapper" a ScrollView.
This should solve the issue.

```
   `return ( 

    <ScrollView>

        // All your other code

    </ScrollView>
);`
```